# Generating video from images like facebook say thanks video

Tags: facebook, video

Which method is used to generate video like Facebook's say thanks video apart from the stupeflix API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook's Say Thanks video is just an imitation of a video using CSS3 transitions and Javascript to generate an image slideshow mixed with multiple transitions and effects. So, not a video.